# Jnuis wont work after asking android for external storage permission. Why?

Tags: python, android, audio, kivy, buildozer

When i run my program with this code:

```
from jnius import autoclass
MediaPlayer = autoclass('android.media.MediaPlayer')
mPlayer = MediaPlayer()

from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
```

It works totally fine, well when i dont do any jnius after asking permission...
I am trying to play sound btw, tried kivy audio but when it loaded the audio (.wav file) it just crashed...

And when i swap the to parts out like so:

```
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])

from jnius import autoclass
MediaPlayer = autoclass('android.media.MediaPlayer')
mPlayer = MediaPlayer()
```

It just crashes after a few seconds...
How do i fix this? I just want to play sounds... (from external storage)

Thx in advance.

Edit:
if i do this:

```
sound = SoundLoader.load('dir/air_spray2.wav')
if sound:
    sound.play()
```

It plays like a tenth of a second of the song and then it just crashes the app(reason why i cant use kivy soundloader)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow found out myself, just delete it

```
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
```

=

and add it to the manifest... not both, just in the manifest...
android.permission =

Comment: well, that is a half ased answer